# How to detect whether camera is in use by another app (iOS/Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, ios-camera

I know we can determine if the device has a camera using `UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable` , but how can we detect if it's being used by another app? In other words, if the green camera icon is present at the upper left of the screen?

Comment: Have you had any resolution for this? @soleil